# Facebook take the wrong image on sharing. (Dynamic image generate for facebook robot)

Tags: facebook, url, dynamic, amazon-s3, share

I know there is a tons of questions about Facebook share... but trust me, I'm trying something different than the normal way of sharing.

Well, I have an Facebook image generate website, but I don't wanna to generate images every time an user enter. So its create an canvas, and then a "og:image" url with an ID..

Then when someone hit the share button, it open the Facebook UI, and:

-Facebook goes into the url with an ID.
-the php script check if the image is already created.
-if not, create the image and save it on amazon S3.
-an finally redirect to the S3 url.

The problem is, if I hit the share btn and post right after it has open... Facebook take an random image of the page.. its like he can't wait the processing and just give up o.o

Someone please know how to prevent it to happen?

Comment: Facebook only takes a “random” image, if you did not properly specify which one to take via Open Graph meta tags.